# Convert nanoseconds (since midnight) to printable time?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have a `uint64_t` representing the number of nanoseconds since midnight. Would std::chrono allow me to convert this into a meaningful "time", relatively simply?

Also, how would I do it if I have the time since epoch?

For example in such a format:

```
14:03:27.812374923
```

And same situation, but when given nanoseconds since epoch? (in case the answer is significantly different)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Howard Hinnant's, free, open-source, header-only library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to do this:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;

    uint64_t since_midnight = 50607812374923;
    cout << make_time(nanoseconds{since_midnight}) << '\n';

    uint64_t since_epoch = 1499522607812374923;
    cout << sys_time<nanoseconds>{nanoseconds{since_epoch}} << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
14:03:27.812374923
2017-07-08 14:03:27.812374923
```

Or did you need to take leap seconds into account for `since_epoch`?

```
    cout << utc_time<nanoseconds>{nanoseconds{since_epoch}} << '\n';

2017-07-08 14:03:00.812374923
```

For this latter computation, you'll need [`"tz.h"` documented here](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), and this library is not header only.